# Elasticsearch query is not working as expected

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have search query like this which is not working and giving me error
**[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]**

```
    array:2 [
  "index" => "esdata"
  "body" => array:1 [
    "query" => array:2 [
      "bool" => array:1 [
        "should" => array:1 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "multi_match" => array:2 [
              "query" => "History"
              "fields" => array:1 [
                0 => "*"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "terms" => array:1 [
        "_id" => array:1 [
          0 => "ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10_*"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

so I changed it to

```
    array:2 [
  "index" => "esdata"
  "body" => array:1 [
    "query" => array:1 [
      "bool" => array:2 [
        "should" => array:1 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "multi_match" => array:2 [
              "query" => "History"
              "fields" => array:1 [
                0 => "*"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
        "must" => array:1 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "match" => array:1 [
              "_id" => "ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10_*"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

but this is giving empty result

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the syntax of PHP, but the first query should be in the below format

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multimatch": {
                        "query": "History",
                        "fields": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "_id": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the second query can be modified into:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multimatch": {
                        "query": "History",
                        "fields": "*"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "_id": "ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10_"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `match` query works on analyzed text, whereas terms query will give you the result only when the search term exactly matches.

Comment: I  tried second query but not working, giving empty result

Comment: @BhumiShah can you please try the 1st query as well, and please share your index mapping as well